# Crystal Report - Display page header starting from certain detail section e.g (Detail c)

Tags: crystal-reports

how can i achieve this?

```
Pageheader 1
Details a <Subreport>
Details b <Subreport>
Details c <Subreport>

Pageheader 2
Details d <Subreport>
Details e <Subreport>
Details f <Subreport>
```

I cannot use the pagenumber to suppress the pageheader because starting pagenumber may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Page Headers will *always* be at the top of each page (once the Report Header has been rendered).

You should probably use a group header.

Comment: yes , i wanted to display the page header at the top of the page :). its just that i want a different page header once details d started at a new page.

Comment: You should update your question to reflect this new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a change in PageHeader depending on certain conditions, you can use two Page Headers. Then suppress one of then when your condition is met.

Comment: please can you give me more steps in creating a  group section. Also each detail section is actually a subreport.

Comment: u need 2 different headers for 2 diff conditions??

Comment: well yeah. the question is how can i suppress the page header 1 when details d  begins. im guessing suppress formula. for example if pagenumber > 3. but i dont want to use pagenumber because you can never tell where detail d will start.

Comment: u got it ! using suppress u can do it. But what is ur condition? tell me ur condition clearly.

Comment: thanks for the reply. detail a b and c are subreports. i want them to be in the same page header. details d e and f are also subreports, and i want them to be under a different page header. i am looking for a suppress formula like suppress if section="details d". how can you reference a section or a subreport? i only know the keyword pagenumber, what else is there?

Answer (score -1):

In Main Report Page Headers you can use number of sub reports but in sub reports Report Header will be take complete page like blank page, so better you have to use entire data into report header section or details section (either one only).